# Calculate $P(1,2428\leq s^2 \leq 2,0773)$ and $P(5,1014\leq \bar{x}\leq6,8986)$

Tags: statistics

Let $x_1,...,x_{15}$ a random sample of size 15 of a normally distributed population with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$

a) Calculate $P(1,2428\leq s^2 \leq 2,0773)$

**My attempt:**

We know $\frac{ns^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi^2_{n-1}$ then

$P(1,2428\leq s^2 \leq 2,0773)=P(\frac{1,2428\times15}{4}\leq\frac{s^2\times n}{\sigma^2}\leq\frac{2,0733\times15}{4})=P(4,66\leq Z\leq 7,78)=\chi_{14}^2(7,78)-\chi^2_{14}(4,66)=(?)$

Here i'm stuck.

b) Suppose $\sigma^2$ is unknow and know $s^2=6,25$ calculate

$$P(5,1014\leq \bar{x}\leq6,8986)$$

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ti-83 or 84 to find the probability using the $\chi^{2}$cdf function.

for part b transform it using a students t distribution.
$t=\frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{s/\sqrt{n}}$ which will have a t-dist with n-1 df. Use tcdf on a calcultor to find the prob.

Comment: also when applying the transformation I do not recommend using Z since it is commonly used for Standard Normal.

Comment: can you be more explicit for the part b? thanks for all